# Плавающая ошибка парсинга json3

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Осваиваю JavaScript+React+Redux и столкнулась с такой ситуацией.
Если в браузере (использую Mozilla Firefox) не открывать окно отладки, то весь написанный код работает без проблем.
Но при открытом отладчике - страница не грузится совсем, а в отладчике при этом такое:
[image]

В чистом виде я нигде не использую JSON. Но незначащие (trailling) запятые были и на всякий случай все убрала - не помогло.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Вот ссылка на проект: https://github.com/jelka2008/SocialNet

Comment: У вас в зависимостях стоит `sockjs-client`, у которого в свою очередь в зависимостях стоит `json3`, а сам пакет `json3` отмечен как _JSON 3 is **deprecated** and **no longer maintained**. Please don't use it in new projects, and migrate existing projects to use the native `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` instead._ И не обновлялся с 2015 года. Может он уже просто несовместим с FF?

Comment: Я всего пол года назад начала изучать JS, а этому проекту и месяца нет. Как ко мне могли попасть старые библиотеки?

Comment: Библиотеки может и новые, только у них внутри старые зависимости. Я не претендую на истину в последней инстанции. Просто предполагаю. Зависимости смотрю в `package-lock.json`. Можете попробовать удалить этот файл (предварительно забэкапившись), удалить папку `node_modules` и выполнить `npm install`

Comment: Проблема была не в зависимостях, но в случайно нажатой кнопке - синяя в правом верхнем углу скрина. У неё, на мой взгляд, странная функция и такое злобное действие

Comment: Кажется понял. Скорей всего было включено "останавливаться на исключениях". В скрипте хоть и используется attempt, но внутри его все же происходит исключение, на котором стопится отладчик